# Add title in the fist column of scraped table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I am currently working on a school project where I am scraping results from a cycling website. I managed to build the scraper to loop through all the urls containing the results. I would like to add the event title to the first column of every table but am facing some difficulties.

Here is my code:

```
# list of needed packages
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import csv

# create string of urls to scrape
urls = ['https://cqranking.com/men/asp/gen/race.asp?raceid=36151', 'https://cqranking.com/men/asp/gen/race.asp?raceid=36151']

# Generates a csv-file named cycling_results.csv, with wanted headers
with open('cycling_results.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow(['Start', 'Rank', '', '', '', 'Name', '', 'Team', '', 'Time', '', 'Points'])

    # loop through all urls in the array
    for url in urls:
        time.sleep(2)
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
        # Find the title of the racing event
        titles = soup.find('title')
        for title in titles:
            writer.writerow(title)
        tables = soup.find_all('table')
        for table in tables:
            rows = table.find_all('tr')
            for row in rows:
                csv_row = []
                columns = row.find_all('td')
                for column in columns:
                    csv_row.append(column.get_text())
                writer.writerow(csv_row)
```

In the next fase I will add code to remove empty rows.

Thank you
Regards
Kevin

Comment: If you use titles = soup.find('title') it will be an element, not a list, so have to re-write code and avoid iterate it. And have to write the text not the element !!

Answer (score 0):

This code should be

```
titles = soup.find('title')
for title in titles:
    writer.writerow(title)
```

---->

```
titles = soup.find('title')
writer.writerow([title.text])
```

find return just an element, not a list of elements. Write element text or your desired info, but not full element

Comment: doesn't writerow require a list so `[title.text]` ?